# SQL - trying to sum value from multiple reference

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a problem to calculate sum of the amount column from some references field in 4 different tables. here is my tables :

First Table (Master) :

```
ID_1 | Name_1
1         A
2         B
```

Second table (Master) :

```
ID_2 | ID_1 | Name_2
 1_1    1      A1
 1_2    1      A2
 2_1    2      B1
 2_2    2      B2
```

Third Table (Transaction) :

```
ID_trans | ID_2 | trans_name | amount | cpy_ID
 trans1    1_1       Rev        123      1400
 trans2    2_1       Dir        321      1400
 trans3    2_1       Ind        231      1400
 trans4    1_2       OTH        234      1400
```

Fourth Table (report template) :

```
report_set_id | report_set_name  |  cpy_ID
     set001        Own Apps          1400
     set002        Third Party       1400
```

The main case is I have to create a report with the third table (transaction) as data reference. And the report template has been determined like this :

```
----------------------------------------------------       
            |      1    |      2      |       TOTAL |------> (1 & 2 first table fields)
----------------------------------------------------
    set001  |  (data 1) |     -       |   (horizontal sum)
    set002  |     -     |  (data 2)   |   (horizontal sum)
-----------------------------------------------------    
    TOTAL   | (sum of 1)| (sum of 2)  |
```

which is :
(data 1 & data 2) = summary data from transaction table with same ID_2 and put in the column 1 rows (bacause ID_1 is foreign key in the second table)

I know my language is complicated to understand cause actually its hard to explaining by words, but I hope you guys can get what exactly I mean it :D

Can someone give me some advice to solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: Do you have two tables with the same name? (Master)

Comment: nope, master and transaction are just the type of my table. Master  mean the data will not updated too often, transaction mean the data will more often updated/added

Comment: @APC ID_2, because ID_2 contain ID_1 in it. In this case I use inner join to call ID_1 using ID_2 value and it work fine

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand all the joins.  
    first_table.id_1 = second_table.id_1  and   
    second_table.id_2 = third_table.id_2   
  
Are those correct?  
  
But what about fourth table?  Are you saying:  

    fourth_table.report_set_id = 'set00' || substr(second_table.id_2, 1, 1) ?

Even if it is correct, that is not a good way to do a join.  It's difficult to answer your question without being able to understand the relationships.  The fourth table should be related to another table using primary and foreign keys, as for the first 3 tables.

Comment: @rigen - yes I figured that out. My question is the same as Bob - what is the relationship between`transaction` and `report template`? How do you know that `(data 1)` belongs in the cell of `1 / set001`  and `(data 2)`  belongs in the cell of `2 / set002` ? Are the numbers meaningful?

Comment: @RonBallard Sorry my mistake, I forgot to add cpy_ID in third and fourth table, I've already edit the tables. So what's ur opinion about this case? should I do the calculation manually using php?

Comment: @APC the relation is on cpy_ID, I apologize for my mistake, I forgot to add cpy_ID

Comment: @Rigen can you post expected sample output?

Comment: @Rigen also in the transaction table for trans3 id_2 should be 2_2, right?

Comment: @Saravana expected output is a determined report like what I say, for the trans3 id_2 is 2_1, cause ID_2 rows in the transaction table can filled with the same value

Comment: @Rigen ok, what is data 1 and data 2? and ID_2 `1_1 & 2_1`  belong to `set0001` and `1_2 & 2_2`  belong to `set0002` always?

Comment: @Saravana which is : (data 1 & data 2) = summary data from transaction table with same ID_2 and put in the column 1 rows (bacause ID_1 is foreign key in the second table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this will only ever have 2 data columns (as labelled "1" and "2" in your example) then it will be quite easy to write in SQL and we could do that.  But if there will be several data columns, and if there will be a variable number of data columns, then we are into the general "pivot table" question.  You can find many discussions on this topic under the [pivot] tag in stackoverflow.  My own opinion is that anything but trivial formatting (including almost all pivot tables) is best done in the application.  Use SQL to group and aggregate the data, then use a visualisation tool, or your application, to format it.  I have written more about this on my [website](http://www.thedatastudio.net/ugly_cross_tab.htm), where I explain a couple of common approaches and why I don't use them.